# Android Actionbar + FragmentActivity

Tags: android

In my application i have tabs but now i need to add Sherlock Actionbar i know that I need use extends SherlockActivity but early I had FragmentActivity how to fix it ?

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
```

Now I have error here beacuse i don't have FragmentActivity.

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Error:

```
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `SherlockFragmentActivity`, I believe, you can extend from that